# Make a synchronous AJAX call before before page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my application, I need to make a `AJAX` call to my server before the page loads to see if the user is logged in or if the session/Authorization Token has expired.

So I am trying to make an AJAX hit in `document.ready`, but this obviously has a few issues including but not limited to:

1. In `document.ready`, first the page will open then the AJAX hit will be sent, that means an extra user-obvious rediction which is not preferable to me.

So, is it possible to make a synchronous AJAX call before before DOM rendering?

Comment: why don't you call your `ajax` right before `<body>` tag? that way, the call is made before the page is fully loaded

Comment: I can, but it would still be asynchronous, so the DOM will be able render before the response

Comment: Ajax is the wrong tool for the job here. This check should happen before the server even sends the response.

Comment: I am using a CDN to deliver my content, so the only way I can ask the server to check something is via a request, isn't it?

Comment: depends on what content comes from the cdn and where the sessions are stored. If you're sending ajax to get session data, surely there's a server there that can do this aswell.

Comment: It's a JWT token sent in the header, from the local storage

Comment: If you make the AJAX call synchronous, why would it "still be asynchronous"?

Comment: TLDR, sending a synchronous ajax request before page load is a bad idea for several reasons, the worst of which is it will significantly impact the perceived page speed. You'll need to use an alternative, such as offloading this work to the server, or re-designing whatever it is you're doing this check for such that it doesn't need to be synchronous or before page load.

Comment: You could set the body CSS to `display: none;`, and then show it after getting the AJAX response.